In samsung tizen tv apps, sometimes set current time for audio html is not working
I am developing audio player for tizen tv apps using audio html5, some times set current time not working with no error.
it is returning mp3 audio back to 0
is audio html5 the correct player for mp3 for tizen 6? did any one face same issue and solved it?

Hello, would you add more detailed information for reviewers? which tools you used? Tizen Studio or somethings.. TV spec used for test, code snippet, etc
